# C++ async + future (deferred vs async)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, c++14

This is the test program that I am working with.  Can someone please describe in detail what is happening and the reason for this output?

Why does `launch::async` get the value of `g_num` as `0`, while `launch::deferred` gets `100`?

Both `launch::async` and `launch::deferred` got correct values of `arg` that is on the `main` stack, which I believe means they should have both gotten `100`.

### The code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
    
thread_local int g_num;
    
int read_it(int x) {
    return g_num + x;
}

int main()
{
    g_num = 100;

    int arg = 1;
    future<int> fut = async(launch::deferred, read_it, arg);
    arg = 2;
    future<int> fut2 = async(launch::async, read_it, arg);

    cout << "Defer: " << fut.get() << endl;
    cout << "Async: " << fut2.get() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### The output:

```
Defer: 101
Async: 2
```

Comment: Try without `thread_local`.

Answer (score 10):

The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) states that `launch::deferred` will invoke the function on the calling thread, while `launch::async` will invoke the function on a new thread.

For the calling thread, the value of `g_num` is whatever you set it to in main. For a new thread, the value is value-initialized (`0` for `int`) since you never set it. Thanks @MilesBudnek for the correction.

Comment: IIRC, globals (including `thread_local` ones) get value-initialized, so the value of `g_num` is well-defined in the worker thread, it's just `0`.

Comment: @merlin2011 So when a new thread is created under, does it look for all `thread_local` variables and set them to default values even when the `thread_local` variable is altered before the new thread is spawned?

Comment: @Seoul: Yes. This is what the `thread_local` qualifier is *for*. Each thread has its own *completely independent* object.

Answer (score 4):

`g_num` is define as `thread_local` this means every thread in your app has its own copy of `g_num`

`launch::deferred` runs on the calling thread. `g_num` on the main thread was changed to 100. It was not changed on the thread that was launched with `launch::async` which is the reason its value was still the default one.